# Put ViewPager in fragment of a menu drawer Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment, pageviews

I searched a solution everywhere but I didnt find anything, so I need one more time your help.

I have a Navigation drawer who works perfectly
[Navigation drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukyV7.jpg)

I have also a ViewPager, that I have take on the Android developer's website. It works fine also.

Now I would like to put the  PageViewer in my "jour" tab for exemple. But the PageViewer is not a "Fragment" but a "ActivityFragment" so I cannot. The help that I can find on the other threads does'nt  match to my problem

How Can I do this ?

Thanks a lot for reading me.

Annex:
Tutorial Android : https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Answer (score 0):

Open your Jour's xml and add the ViewPager Tag.

Then open Jour's java and bind an object of ViewPager with the xml. Add the adapter to the viewpager object and you are done.

Comment: thanks , you said "add the ... " Is it missing a word? I will try your solution

Comment: I have do that you say but My fragment is display in all the activity so my navigation drawer is hidden

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i should create a new thread or not. I have put the code in the main activity but the fragment cover all the activity. [screen of the fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yliLY.png)
It is strange because the other fragments work.

main Activity

```
TestSlideFragment fragment = new TestSlideFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.RelativeLayout_for_Fragment, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

layout of the fragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="oytoch.iut_info.test.TestSlideFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: In your TestSlidefragment, add the ViewPager instance and set up a adapter.

Comment: I'm really lost, sorry. I will rely on your solution to solve this problem. Thanks a lot for your help. have a good day.